# Review "First Posts" auditing dodge

Tags: feature-request, bug, review-queues, review-audits

I've noticed there's an easy way to circumvent the "First Posts" review queue auditing (and quite possibly that of others) by *dummying* a downvote.  If this was a "test" and was deliberately "bad", you will be instantly notified that you `passed` the test.  Otherwise you simply retract the downvote.

A small fix can improve tykes like me from cheating the system.

So I suggest that:

you have to click "I'm Done" before the audit result is processed

Comment: Lol. Bites you in the ass if it was a good post.  But I still think retraction should be forbidden here

Comment: This is the right place. However, have you ever passed a "good" audit by doing this? Downvoting should fail those audits

Comment: Yeah bradders aka @BradleyDotNET, but if you're 50% sure then you may risk it. My opinion is that one should be 95% positive before casting judgment (if theyre not a miscreant like me)

Comment: Let's have some strategy and higher level philosophy now; I'm a very sceptical reviewer, so this could leave what SO would consider "ok" as being negatively reviewed by me, simply because I am concious of the auditors.

Comment: There isn't much you can do about it though. Say you remove retraction from the audit window. A "clever" reviewer like you could *still* just go to the question and retract it directly. And even if your remove grace-period retraction entirely, you can *still* retract after an edit (even a "ghost" one, which you can't do yet). At some point, we have to trust our reviewers. Now, if you were just suggesting that you have to click "I'm Done" before the audit result is processed, I could get behind *that*.

Comment: I'll take *clever* over lots of other things I've been called.  Italicised thought it may be =DD

Comment: @BradleyDotNET "[...] you have to click "I'm Done" before the audit result is processed".  Let's DO it!!!

Comment: I wonder if this feature-request should be on MSE? DO all sites have the same review/audit system which this question covers?

Comment: Audits are intended to make sure you're paying attention. You'll always be able to "cheat" by opening the post in another tab to see if it's an audit. It doesn't matter; if you're paying enough attention to suspect that an item might be an audit, *it has already done its job*.

Comment: Easiest method of dodging these is to setup a filter on the questions you are reviewing...if question does not conform to your filter, it's an audit.

Comment: @AirThomas  "*if you're paying enough attention to suspect that an item might be an audit, it has already done its job*" Scenario: A user, on every single review, clicks downvote, waits 1 second to see if they get a "Congratulations this was a audit" message, if not revert the downvote (or not, even) and clicks "I'm done/Nothing needed"? This is a 2 second process to circumvent the system. So I disagree that paying enough attention has been done to make the audit have "already done it's job". This proposal would stop this scenario.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What a great suggestion!
I cannot think of a single reason why this wouldn't be great (although I'm sure someone will :P)

I've ground my teeth so many times at the way audits work.
It's often obvious when a review is actually an audit, and, as you said, one just clicks downvote (or flag or whatever) to get your "Congratulations..".
If that doesn't happen, you just cancel/revert whatever you did.
(I only do this when I think it's an audit, I otherwise review like a good boy...)

Even users who don't know the tricks to ID an audit, I suspect many will just click vote or flag by habit to test if current review is an audit.

So your suggestion that your actions are not *evaluated* in an audit until you "submit" them, should resolve:.

1. Being able to test if review is an audit
2. Stop ability to pass audits easily/quickly
3. Possibly catch (and thereby punish) more robo reviewers
4. Possibly stop some robo reviewers being bad

3 & 4 - Robo reviewers won't be wanting to click "skip", so if they cannot ID an audit, they might just click "No action" more often  and therefore be caught out, and so potentially suspended from reviewing etc.
And if they don't, then job done as they're now having to action reviews a little more carefully as they cannot ID an audit.

Comment: "No Action" can fail audits. The only guaranteed way out is to "Skip".

Comment: Robo reviewers won't be wanting to click "skip" as they don't get rep. Which is why I said it would either catch them out, or make them review better (*possibly*).

Comment: Gotcha, didn't understand what you meant by "caught out".

Comment: Updated answer, possibly wasn't clear TBH. I have a habit of writing opinion into the internet and thinking others know what I mean sometimes without enough detail.

Comment: @James There is no rep for reviewing, is there?

Comment: @RetoKoradi There is the reputation you gain from having nice badges.

Answer (score 12):

Who cares? There's always a guaranteed way to cheat: open the post in a separate tab. If the post score is different, it's an audit. Last time I checked, it worked with all review types.

The only difference with your solution is the number of mouse clicks. And I doubt it's even reliable, considering audits can expect either an upvote or a downvote, IIRC.

Receiving review results before finishing reviews was a serious issue in the close vote queue, because it caused failed audits when checking votes of others, but in the first post queue it doesn't really matter, I think.

Comment: The point wasn't really about *prevention*.  Just cutting down on lazy reviewers doing a poor job, which we can mitigate for, albeit only slightly. It may contribute to improving quality and carefulness. PS: I would describe myself as a lazy reviewer - and I've never once tried the trick you mentioned (until now ;D).

Comment: "There's always a guaranteed way to cheat" That's the same as most enforcement, in all life. Do we not bother with locks on our home doors as burglars will find a way in if they really want to? Shouldn't we welcome being able to make audits more stringent? If you feel the change is not necessary, please do give reasons why. Simplifying the change to "the only difference being mouse clicks" is not really fair, as those "only mouse clicks" means we might catch robo reviewers out, or at least make them review better. Anything can be simplified to a generic description to make it sound pointless