# Review First Posts Queue audit questions discourage substantive/personalized comments

Tags: discussion, comments, review-audits, first-post-review

It is exhausting when I spend some time crafting an encouraging comment for a question or answer that needs improvement, and then I am told "I passed the test".

It leads to me wanting to game the system as per *[Review "First Posts" auditing dodge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280676/review-first-posts-auditing-dodge)*. Workflow: Downvote a problematic question so I can tell whether it is is a test. Mainly I forget anyway, and I lose interest in reviewing once I put in some time making a comment.

None of the other queues seem to have this onerous quality. I have to imagine that it must discourage others as well.

I'm tempted to suggest removing the audit questions from this queue. No harm is really done if a person makes an error. I'd never considered there was such a thing as a robo-reviewer!

Perhaps the question can stay in the queue for a while and multiple folks can act on it. That way they'd eventually get judged correctly, and I think this might even be a way to stop robo-reviewers.

Comment: Yes there is harm without the audits.  Robo reviewers would approve everything and a bunch of bad content would make it to/be on the site.

Comment: `"Perhaps the question can stay in the queue for a while and multiple folks can act on it."` I'm fairly positive it does that already anyway.

Comment: @SandPiper no, only one review is required for First Posts (and Late Answers).

Comment: If you feel that something you do takes more effort than it's worth then I would suggest stop doing it.

Comment: It really isn't supposed to be difficult. Perhaps you are leaving comments too much of the time when you should be either flagging or voting silently?

Comment: I guess that's my point.  Why should the system dictate that a flag or silent vote is the way a user responds?

The first posts queue is something that marks a first encounter between a user and a community.  I would think it lends itself towards making a welcoming/encouraging comment over and above all the others.  That's my impulse.  I seems to me application is thwarting that.

Comment: @RobertMoskal If you want to post a comment *in addition* to flagging content that merits a flag, then sure, go right ahead, but not flagging content that merits a flag is a big problem, and you failing to do what's required of you in the queue is a problem, as the audits are indicating.

Comment: The audits work fine.  I am flagged for allowing something to stand as it is.  The tool accepts a comment as a legit intervention without a flag or a downvote.  Why would it accept that if it wasn't the right thing to do.

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure if you're talking about positive (good posts) or negative (bad posts) audits (you can comment on either of them, it doesn't matter for passing the audit). In both cases, you can choose to up-/downvote *before* you post a comment; this will automatically reveal if it's an audit or not.

> I'm tempted to suggest removing the audit questions from this queue. No harm is really done if a person makes an error.

I think you misunderstand the purpose of audits. They aren't there for checking if people make errors now and then; they are there to prevent so-called robo-reviewers from blindly clicking the <kbd>No action needed</kbd> button (or any other button), just to gain badges as fast as possible.

> It leads to me wanting to game the system as per Review "First Posts" auditing dodge.

That could be; in that case, please stop reviewing and find another way to contribute to Stack Overflow (e.g. posting questions and answers; nobody *compels* you to review).

> None of the other queues seem to have this onerous quality.

*Au contraire*: you can comment in **all** review queues (except Suggested Edits) even when confronted with audits.

Comment: The first posts queue is something that marks a first encounter between a user and a community.  I would think it lends itself towards making a welcoming/encouraging comment over and above all the others.  That's my impulse.  I seems to me application is thwarting that.

Comment: @RobertMoskal true; a tool which helps with this is [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/34061). It's easy to customize your own comment (template) into this tool, e.g. something like *Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have a moment, please read the [tour].* This saves you a lot of typing.

Comment: I hear you.  My comments definitely fall into categories. Sometimes I want to make a  substantive or personalized comment.   When that happens in a audit, I fell spanked.